# If a LLC doesn’t file as a corporation on federal income tax, what are other options?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, corporation

What are other filing options for no income LLCs?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the option of not filing federal taxes, from [this IRS page](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/small-business-self-employed-other-business/entities/entities-4).

> A domestic partnership must file an information return, unless it
> neither receives gross income nor pays or incurs any amount treated as
> a deduction or credit for federal tax purposes.

If you wish to file, and it is a single-member LLC, you can file as a sole proprietor. Use schedule C in your personal taxes.

Partnership, C-corp and S-corp are the other options, discussed [here](https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/business/trends-and-insights/articles/4-tax-possibilities-for-your-llc/).

Comment: How does one know if any amounts are credits or deductions?

Comment: @Germania the members have to file all that proportionally on their personal tax return. if there are multiple members, send a K-1 if there is just one member, do it all on the personal tax return.

Comment: If you don't wish to claim deductions for the LLC, you don't have to claim them. That would make the no-filing option possible. If you want to claim deductions, you have to file in order to claim them.